# Compiz 0.9 issue: Couldn't open display

Tags: ubuntu, display, compiz

I decided that I would like Compiz 0.9 on my computer, which runs Ubuntu 10.10. I followed the instructions on this Compiz [wiki page](http://wiki.compiz.org/C%2B%2BCompiling); some lines I changed. I now have compiled and installed Compiz core, libcompizconfig, compizconfig-python, ccsm, plugin pack 'main', and plugin pack 'extra'. Running the command in bash:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages /usr/local/bin/ccsm`

to start CompizConfig Settings Manager works and CCSM works beautifully. When I attempt to start Compiz itself, however, I get this:

`compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display H���`

Running compiz through sudo I get this:

`compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display ������`

I have noticed that those strange symbols at the end change every time I try to run Compiz.

The value of the environment variable DISPLAY is :0. Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Thanks! (I'm not sure if this question is in the right place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I used GDB to trace the message being outputted - it turns out that Compiz expects a CLI argument "--display" and a value for (in this case, $DISPLAY or ":0"), which I wasn't providing. However, other problems prevented me from using Compiz, so I am removing it. I am currently in the process of getting Compiz 0.9.2 through the Unity PPA on my Ubuntu system; if that doesn't work, I'll downgrade back to 0.8.x.